# kable: Vertical alignment does not work with pdf output

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I am trying to produce a large table in pdf mixing text and figures using `kable`. I am trying to align every row to the top. I made an example using a figure test.jpg located inside the working directory. I am using the version 1.22 of `knitr`.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
table <- data.frame(
  col1 = "test", 
  col2 = "![test](test.jpg){width=150px}")
knitr::kable(table)
```
````

It behaves correctly and aligns the figure and the text to the top if I knit it in html but it aligns the figure and the text at the bottom using the pdf. Specifying the `valign` option does not change the behavior.

[image: Exemple]

Did anyone experience a similar behavior ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a good solution, but I have a workaround. It's a cludge that uses the LaTeX package `adjustbox` – specifically, `valign = T` as an argument to `includegraphics`. (The `scale = 0.5` just makes the image 50% its original size.) I've also thrown in an escaped linebreak (`\\\\`) for the sake of prettiness.

````
---
title: \textbf{Title}
author: \normalfont{Author}
output:
  pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
---

```{r}
table <- dplyr::tibble(
  col1 = LETTERS[1:3], 
  col2= c("\\includegraphics[valign=T, scale=0.5]{Osedax_roseus.jpg} \\\\",
          "\\includegraphics[valign=T, scale=0.5]{Osedax_roseus.jpg} \\\\",
          "\\includegraphics[valign=T, scale=0.5]{Osedax_roseus.jpg} \\\\"))
knitr::kable(table, format = "latex", escape = FALSE)
```
````

[image]

This example uses the photo from [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osedax).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Only one last thing, do you know if there is any way to quit the little space on the top the picture? In order to have a perfect alignment between the figure and the text of the first column

Comment: @Klone As an argument to `includegraphics` along with `valign` and `scale`, you can add `raise=3mm` (or whatever distance) to scoot it up a bit. As I say, it's a cludge, but that seems to be how LaTeX rolls. <shrug>

Comment: thanks. ok it works for what I want to do. I am using:  `\\includegraphics[valign=T, scale=0.5, raise= 2mm]{test.jpg} \\vspace{1.00mm}` and it works perfectly fine to print a data.frame using the `kable` package.

Comment: @Klone Glad to hear it works and apologies for not having a more elegant solution!

Comment: @Lyngbakr: would you have any recommendations on how to address this related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285820/kableextra-vertical-alignment-not-working-in-pdf-output-with-many-columns 
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @Lyngbakr - I'm trying to adapt this solution for my purposes but struggling a bit. Is the adjustbox package necessary for this to work?

Comment: @nad7wf Yes, I believe it is.